# Segmentation fault on recv()

Tags: c

I am writing client/server programs on Unix in C, using send/recv. I am occasionally getting a segmentation fault from a recv call. The behavior is not perfectly reproducible; sometimes it happens, and sometimes the program runs to completion.

Any ideas what this could mean?

Answer (score 6):

If the segmentation fault is in the `recv()` call itself, then that implies that the buffer you passed to `recv()` is not properly allocated or is not the size that you told `recv()` it was.

Comment: Hmm...but why would it not be 100% reproducible?

Comment: Because invoking undefined behavior does not give reproducible results. Just listen to caf's advice and fix the incorrect size or memory-corruption bugs in your code.

Comment: @User432944: All that means is that sometimes the overlap happened to go into a page your process doesn't own, and other times it just stomped across a random bit of memory you do own.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it usually means you're receiving more data than your buffer has allowed for.

For example, if you `malloc` 20 bytes and `recv` 1000 bytes, you'll run into this problem.

Unfortunately, without seeing the code, and without some very rapid advances in the field of psychic debugging, we'll never know for sure <sup>*a</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>*a</sup> That's a subtle hint to post the code, by the way :-)</sup>

Comment: So subtle I almost missed it.

Answer (score 0):

This could also mean that the socket on the other side is closed before you write to it.
That is a SIGPIPE that may be causing your application to close.

Comment: That's not quite true, a SIGPIPE is not the same as a segmentation fault. Also, he mentioned that it is problematic on the `recv` call.

Comment: SIGPIPE doesn't cause a segmentation fault; it just exits.  Also, the SIGPIPE would occur on the writing side when there's no receiver, but that doesn't apply to `recv()` - it might apply to `send()`.